# What is Hyperledger?

Tags: hyperledger

Can you explain Hyperledger for someone who already knows what blockchains are? Their website is really vague and provides minimal information, including a definition as "communities of software developers building blockchain frameworks and platforms". Wikipedia page for Hyperledger gives the impression that it's a set of modular tools that can be adapted for blockchain projects. Then again I've listened to pitches of a few Hyperledger projects and they talk about running their stuff "on" Hyperledger, like they had a distinct blockchain that multiple projects run on. But is it more like a make-your-own-blockchain toolkit?

Comment: This is not Wikipedia.

Comment: [Hyperledger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperledger) is on Wikipedia. In general, Wikipedia, the fount of all knowledge, is the fount of all knowledge.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: agree with C-Otto : This is not Wikipedia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hyperledger is a collection of blockchain related projects.  Pitches that claim they are running their stuff on Hyperledger most likely means they are using Fabric or Sawtooth, although more likely than not Fabric, to implement the blockchain they are using.  Fabric is one of the Hyperledger projects that provides a permissioned blockchain implementation that adheres to the Fabric protocols which define how the network components interact.  There is no single Hyperledger blockchain, just like there is no single MySQL databases.

Answer (score 4):

Hyperledger is a technology initiative, not a single project.  In fact, several dozen projects are currently in development under that umbrella.

If someone is contrasting Hyperledger with Ethereum, they are probably specifically talking about Hyperledger Fabric.  In fact, there is actually an Ethereum node project *within* Hyperledger-- Hyperledger Burrow!  ( You can check that out here: https://github.com/hyperledger/burrow )

So, your first careful question if you are trying to detect bullshit in this space should be to figure out if the person knows what substrate they are using-- Fabric, Burrow, or something else entirely!

Of equal value, make sure they understand that Hyperledger is not just (or even primarily) IBM!

Now, if you ARE talking about Hyperledger Fabric vs. Ethereum, probably the most important difference is to recognize that Fabric does not necessarily inform the entire network about all transactions, whereas for Ethereum this is a given.  Fabric allows different chains ("sidechains"-ish) to be spun up on demand between a subset of nodes on the network.  This allows, in principle, different competing businesses in an industry to peer-validate public transactions, but also to maintain private smart contracts between a limited set of entities.

More interesting is the potential to build a top-level public contract that requires the results of privately-held parts, so long as they meet certain criteria.

But the super-short version is: Fabric allows privacy; Ethereum mandates global transparency.  Which approach is "better" very much depends on the application.

Answer (score 2):

Hyperledger is the open-source blockchain initiative sponsored by the Linux Foundation. The phrase "Hyperledger" is a trademark of Digital Asset Holdings. There are many projects under the umbrella, but the main project contributed by IBM is the Fabric. www.hyperledger.org has more info. Hyperledger focuses on permissioned blockchain technology as compared against public blockchains like Ethereum.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger is not a company, not a cryptocurrency. Hyperledger is rather something like a hub for open industrial blockchain development. Hyperledger does not support Bitcoin or any other cryptocurrency. But the platform is thrilled by blockchain technology.

Hyperledger does not intend to establish any kind of Hyperledger coin. Hyperledger Project is an open source, collaborative effort to create a blockchain for business-to-business (B2B) and business-to-customer (B2C) transactions.

Hyperledger blockchains are generally permissioned blockchains, which means that the parties that join the network are authenticated and authorized to participate on the network. Hyperledger does not refer to any specific technology or tool rather it refers to a project where multiple teams are collaborating to develop open source and distributed ledger technology (DLT).